# Java Websocket wait for response before making next request to the same socket

Tags: java, websocket

```
public WebSocket connect() throws Exception {
WebSocket ws = new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT).createSocket(SERVER)
.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
System.out.println(message);
}

public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, java.util.Map headers) {
System.out.println(websocket.getSocket().toString());
System.out.println(headers.toString());
logger.logInfo("QlikWebConnector", "connect", "connection: ",
websocket.getSocket().toString() + headers.toString());
}

public void onMessageError(com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket websocket,
com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException cause, java.util.List frames)
throws java.lang.Exception {
}

public void onSendError(com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket websocket,
com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException cause,
com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame frame) throws java.lang.Exception {
}

public void onBinaryMessage(com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket websocket, byte[] binary)
throws java.lang.Exception {
}

public void onDisconnected(com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket websocket,
com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame serverCloseFrame,
com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame clientCloseFrame, boolean closedByServer)
throws java.lang.Exception {
}
}).addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE).connect();
if (ws.isOpen()) {
System.out.println("websocket is open ");
logger.logInfo("QlikWebConnector", "connect", "websocket is open: ", "websocket is open");
}
return ws;
}
```

I am sending request like:-
1) ws.sendText("my message1")  2)ws.sendText("my message2")

What is happening?
1) both requests get fired at the same time.

Problem/Expected:-
1) I want my socket to wait till first request get processed as my second request is dependent on response of first request.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is to change the logic of your program a little. For example, instead of sending both messages at the same time and from the same place, you can send the first message and listen for the response. After getting a response for the first message - you can send the second one.

Something like this:

```
public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
    if (shouldSendSeccondMessage(message)) {
        sendSeccondMessage();
    }
}
```

If you have some state and according to the state you send a particular message - then you can think about using the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). So, for each message, your state machine will decide the next step(message).